# Frankendphp with laravel not auto reload using the default compose .yaml

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I use the default frankenphp docker compose .yaml file

```
# compose.yaml

services:
  php:
    image: dunglas/frankenphp
    # uncomment the following line if you want to use a custom Dockerfile
    #build: .
    # uncomment the following line if you want to run this in a production environment
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80" # HTTP
      - "443:443" # HTTPS
      - "443:443/udp" # HTTP/3
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    # comment the following line in production, it allows to have nice human-readable logs in dev
    tty: true

# Volumes needed for Caddy certificates and configuration
volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

Even it have already specify the volume for app `./:/app`, when the code change, the UI is not auto reloaded, I have to reload it manually to make it works.

Is there any way to make it more automatic?